# Why will the synchronous continuations no longer be executed synchronously?

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library, taskcompletionsource

In the [following article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-1-asyncmanualresetevent/), Stephen Toub describes how to build a `ManualResetEvent` using the TPL. In particular, he states that in the following method:

```
public void Set()
{
    var tcs = m_tcs;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(
        s => ((TaskCompletionSource<bool>)s).TrySetResult(true),
        tcs,
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness,
        TaskScheduler.Default);
    tcs.Task.Wait();
}
```

the `tcs.Task.Wait()` will *"block until the task being completed is actually finished (not including the task’s synchronous continuations, just the task itself)"*.  Why won't we block on any synchronous continuations?  That is, what will prevent any synchronous continuations on any Tasks awaiting tcs.Task's completion from executing synchronously?

Comment: BTW. The referenced article is 10 years old (2012).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He means that if you do is this way:

```
public void Set()
{
    m_tsc.TrySetResult(true);
}
```

Then all synchronous continuations of `TaskCompletionSource` Task will run synchronously on this same thread, blocking `Set` method for the duration.

However if you do it the way described in your question, then all those continuations will still run, but on thread pool thread, because that's where you execute `TrySetResult`. As soon as `TaskCompletionSource` task completes - your `tcs.Task.Wait()` will return, *before* synchronous continuations will run. So in effect, `Set` method will not block waiting for them to complete.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the work in ContinueWith is a different task. All [ContinueWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=net-7.0) variants say:

> **Returns**
>
> A new continuation Task.

and in the Remarks we can read:

> **Remarks**
>
> The returned Task will not be scheduled for execution until the current task has completed.

---

BTW. These days `ContinueWith` is discouraged and `await` is preferred in almost all cases.

Comment: Continuations may be separate tasks, but according to the same article, they can supposedly be made to execute synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

> the `tcs.Task.Wait()` will *"block until the task being completed is actually finished (not including the task’s synchronous continuations, just the task itself)"*.  Why won't we block on any synchronous continuations?  That is, what will prevent any synchronous continuations on any Tasks awaiting tcs.Task's completion from executing synchronously?

Your question is about [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task)s in general, not about the [`TaskCompletionSource.Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource.task) in particular. The answer is that when an incomplete `Task` is waited, the `Wait` is performed by a [`ManualResetEventSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualreseteventslim), which is `Set` by a task continuation, which is prioritized in front of all other continuations that might be attached previously. Here is a part of the private [`SpinThenBlockingWait`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/5c9f30616c87af1d33f176481ddc33b05900a1c3/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L3004) method, from the `Task.cs` source code:

```
private bool SpinThenBlockingWait(int millisecondsTimeout,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    bool infiniteWait = millisecondsTimeout == Timeout.Infinite;
    uint startTimeTicks = infiniteWait ? 0 : (uint)Environment.TickCount;
    bool returnValue = SpinWait(millisecondsTimeout);
    if (!returnValue)
    {
        var mres = new SetOnInvokeMres();
        try
        {
            AddCompletionAction(mres, addBeforeOthers: true);
            if (infiniteWait)
            {
                bool notifyWhenUnblocked = ThreadPool.NotifyThreadBlocked();
                try
                {
                    returnValue = mres.Wait(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken);
                    //...
```

This method is invoked internally by the [`Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait), when the task is not complete at the moment, and the current thread must be blocked. The `SetOnInvokeMres` is a small class that inherits from the `ManualResetEventSlim`:

```
private sealed class SetOnInvokeMres : ManualResetEventSlim, ITaskCompletionAction
{
    internal SetOnInvokeMres() : base(false, 0) { }
    public void Invoke(Task completingTask) { Set(); }
    public bool InvokeMayRunArbitraryCode => false;
}
```

The interesting point is the `addBeforeOthers: true` argument. This ensures that the `ManualResetEventSlim` will be signaled **before** invoking any continuation that is associated with user-supplied code. The Task Parallel Library exposes no public API that allows to attach a continuation with `addBeforeOthers: true`. Actually this parameter seems to exist exclusively for supporting the signaling of `ManualResetEventSlim`s with priority.